# A question on function with two criteria .

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(n) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{n^5} - 6n} & {n,}  \\
   {7n + 1} & {n,}  \\
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {is}  \\
   {is}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {even}  \\
   {odd}  \\
\end{array}$

Is may be written function $f(n)$ with one criteria ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since

$f(n) = \frac{{{{( - 1)}^n} + 1}}{2}({n^5} - 6n) + \frac{{{{( - 1)}^n} - 1}}{{ - 2}}(7n + 1)$

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same as H.S. and grouping, you can simplify his/her result to $$f(n)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(n^5+n+1\right)+(-1)^n \left(n^5-13 n-1\right)\right)$$

Comment: Dear **Claude Leibovici** if $f(n) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{n^5} - 6n} & {n,}  \\
   {7n^2 + 1} & {n,}  \\
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {is}  \\
   {is}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {even}  \\
   {odd}  \\
\end{array}$ ,what is answer this question?

Comment: @H.S. I am not sure I understand your question. What you answered is very good. I just rewrote your expression (I think). Could you clarify ? By the way $+1$ for your answer. Cheers.